# Why would this rspec fail for basic "put update" using rspec scaffolding?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Why would rspec say "received: 0 times" in the following rspec message from a basic rspec put update as listed below?

```
Failures:

    1) KeywordsController PUT update with valid params updates the requested keyword
Failure/Error: Keyword.any_instance.should_receive(:update_attributes).with({:id => keyword.id, :keyword => {:name => 'keyword name changed'}})
(#<Mocha::ClassMethods::AnyInstance:0x007fc90bfcc7c8>).update_attributes({:id=>853, :keyword=>{:name=>"keyword name changed"}})
    expected: 1 time with arguments: ({:id=>853, :keyword=>{:name=>"keyword name changed"}})
    received: 0 times with arguments: ({:id=>853, :keyword=>{:name=>"keyword name changed"}})
    # ./spec/controllers/keywords_controller_spec.rb:121:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

keywords_controller_spec.rb

```
describe KeywordsController do
  describe "PUT update" do
    context "with valid params" do
      it "updates the requested keyword" do
        keyword = create(:keyword)
        Keyword.any_instance.should_receive(:update_attributes).with({:id => keyword.id, :keyword => {:name => 'keyword name changed'}})
        put :update, {:id => keyword.id, :keyword => {:name => 'keyword name changed'}}, valid_session
      end
    end
end
```

keywords_controller.rb:

```
class KeywordsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @keyword = Keyword.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @keyword.update_attributes(params[:keyword])
        flash[:notice] = t('controllers.keywords.update.success.keyword_updated')
        format.json { render :json => @keyword.to_json, :status => 200 }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
        format.html { redirect_to(edit_keyword_path(@keyword)) }
      else
        format.json { render :text => "Could not update keyword.", :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @keyword.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        format.html { render :action => :edit, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: check the test output in `log/test.log`. You may have filters (eg. authentication) that prevent the action from ever being reached.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but since you are setting your expectations after creating the instance of Keyword, it's possible the expectations aren't set on it.  If `Keyword.find()` is pulling that object out of a cache, instead of re-creating it, it'd fail.

Try this:

```
describe KeywordsController do
  describe "PUT update" do
    context "with valid params" do
      it "updates the requested keyword" do
        Keyword.any_instance.should_receive(:update_attributes).with({:id => keyword.id, :keyword => {:name => 'keyword name changed'}})
        keyword = create(:keyword)
        put :update, {:id => keyword.id, :keyword => {:name => 'keyword name changed'}}, valid_session
      end
    end
end
```

Or, move the expectation onto the object itself (again this is really only if it's being fetched from a cache):

```
describe KeywordsController do
  describe "PUT update" do
    context "with valid params" do
      it "updates the requested keyword" do
        keyword = create(:keyword)
        keyword.should_receive(:update_attributes).with({:id => keyword.id, :keyword => {:name => 'keyword name changed'}})
        put :update, {:id => keyword.id, :keyword => {:name => 'keyword name changed'}}, valid_session
      end
    end
end
```

Worth a try!

Comment: Thanks for the interesting suggestions!  Tried the first and would not pass because of the missing reference to keyword.id in the expectation.  And the 2nd option produces the same initial error message. Will keeping digging!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
In my case, using `expect_any_instance_of(Model)` instead of `Model.any_instance` pass the test.
I still can't figure out why though.

Hope this help.

```
describe KeywordsController do
  describe "PUT update" do
    context "with valid params" do
      it "updates the requested keyword" do
        keyword = create(:keyword)
        expect_any_instance_of(Keyword).to receive(:update_attributes).with({:id => keyword.id, :keyword => {:name => 'keyword name changed'}})
        put :update, {:id => keyword.id, :keyword => {:name => 'keyword name changed'}}, valid_session
      end
    end
end
```